# Evince 3.10 toolbar hides with no obvious way to restore it on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, pdf, evince

I just installed Lubuntu 13.10, replacing Lubuntu 13.04. I have my `/home` directory on a separate partition, so all my files and settings etc. are right where they are. This also meant I now have Evince 3.10. On Lubuntu 13.04, I think I had Evince 3.8 (not sure), but it had a menubar and a toolbar. I've hidden the toolbar, but the menubar was still available.

Now, when I open a pdf, I see neither the toolbar nor the menubar. I learnt that the menubar has been removed in favor of a more powerful toolbar in Evince 3.10, but couldn't find anything on the net as to why my toolbar is hidden. Then, I noticed that if I go fullscreen with <kbd>F11</kbd> and back with <kbd>ESC</kbd>, the toolbar shows up. But again disappears as soon as I click on the pdf page.

So, I thought I'd try and clear all the evince settings, but I couldn't find much. There is no `~/.config/evince`. The only thing that I found seems to be related to this problem is `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`. If I clear out that folder, and open a pdf, the toolbar shows up correctly and behaves right. Until I close it and open it again that is. If evince saves a file called `home` in that directory, then the next time I open the pdf, the toolbar is gone. If I clear the folder again, the toolbar appears.

I'm not sure if all this is intentional, but if that is the case, all I want is how do I summon the toolbar when its hidden, when I need to check the page number I'm in, for example.

Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install `dconf-editor`
- Follow path `/org/gnome/evince/default/`, check `show-toolbar`

Comment: Nice suggestion but no effect. The toolbar still appears and disappears based on an imaginary coin flip. At any point, I can't seem to figure out how to make the toolbar to show up. Any other ideas?

Comment: Correction: Actually, this does work for new pdf files. Not on the ones that I've previously opened. I think evince remembers settings on a per-pdf basis. Either way, this is the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always install install atril. It's the fork of evince in the MATE desktop, and it keeps the Gnome 2 look. File Edit etc across the top.