# Reactivate menu in Evince

Tags: 13.10, menu, evince

The new Evince for 13.10 without a menu bar mostly sucks from a usability perspective, but I've gradually gotten used to it.

However, I seem to have gotten myself into a situation where even the button I normally use to bring up the menu has disappeared. I can print by pressing Ctrl-P, so not all functionality is lost, but I can't recover the menu.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384536/evince-3-10-toolbar-hides-with-no-obvious-way-to-restore-it-on-lubuntu) seems to be the same, but for Lubuntu.

Note: only certain documents open in this way. For others, the toolbar is present.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the gear button on the upper right? You should get the menu from there.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a long time I discovered that the gear is hidden if the evince window is too narrow. So widen the window to see the gear.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the problem. Sometimes the gear disappears and I can't bring it back. Can still print with Ctrl-P, but it's otherwise a pain. True also with Ubuntu 14.04.