# 'Go to page' keyboard shortcut in Evince 3.10.3?

Tags: shortcut-keys, evince

I can't seem to find the keyboard shortcut that allows me to select the page number.

What is it? Or if it doesn't exist, how can I add one?

I'm using Evince 3.10.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 6):

The shortcut to focus the page entry should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. That's what it is for evince 3.4.0, at least.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, and the new version of Evince came along with it. I seem to remember it being `CTRL`+`L` as well...

Comment: @DanielQue Works on Ubuntu 16.04 Evince 3.18.2. Is `L` is a mnemonic for `Location`? Could not find any GUI indication of it however... Edit: ah, now that I've tried fullscreen, I see what happens: the top menu, which is shown by `Ctrl + L` is an autohide on hover thing. Only it fails to unhide when not in fullscreen..... Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384536/evince-3-10-toolbar-hides-with-no-obvious-way-to-restore-it-on-lubuntu

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04.